# How to Get the number of the displayed row in wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row

For winform datagridview , we can use "**DisplayedRowCount**" to get the number of the displayed row, How can i get it for wpf datagrid.  Thank you~~
  Rui

Answer (score -1):

You'll find the answer here;

http://xceed.com/CS/forums/thread/25456.aspx

Pass it to a StaticResource

from there you can use the count method on the object.

Answer (score -1):

You could get the number of rows like this, and display it in the datagrid tab, if say you were displaying a list of movie tickets. Please note that here instead of using a WPF `TabControl` I ended up using a `Grid` and `StackPanels` because of some difficulty I had with the `TabControl` in working with command execution:

In your Resources.resx, have an item like this:

```
  <data name="MovieTicketsDataGridTitle" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Tickets ({0})</value>
  </data>
```

Then in your XAML file have:

```
        <!--  Table header  -->
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" ">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Label Name="MovieTicketsDataGridTitle" 
                           Margin="0,0,20,0" 
                           Content="{Binding MovieTicketCount, ConverterParameter={x:Static resx:Resources.MovieTicketsDataGridTitle}, Converter={StaticResource DataGridHeaderCountConverter}}" 
                           MouseDown="MovieTicketsDataGridTitle_MouseDown">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown" >
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MovieTicketsHeaderMouseDown}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Label>
               </StackPanel >
                <Button Grid.Column="2" 
                        Width="30" 
                        Height="30" 
                        Margin="0,0,10,0" 
                        Background="Transparent" 
                        BorderThickness="0" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ., Source={x:Reference MovieTicketsDataGrid}}"
                        Visibility="{Binding MovieTicketsGridVisibility}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                        <Image Width="30" Height="30" Source="/Track Inspection;component/Icons/myTicketBtn.png" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
       <controls:CustomDataGrid Name="MovieTicketsDataGrid" Grid.Row="1"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                CanUserAddRows="False"
                                CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                                CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                                CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                                CanUserResizeRows="False"
                                HeadersVisibility="Column"
                                Visibility="{Binding MovieTicketGridVisibility}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding MovieTicketCollectionView.View}"
                                NoDataText="{x:Static resx:Resources.DataGridNoData}"
                                RowHeight="60"
                                RowSelectionCommand="{Binding NavigateToMovieTicketDetails}"
                                VerticalGridLinesBrush="#3D9799">
            <controls:CustomDataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0" />
                </Style>
            </controls:CustomDataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <!--  Date  -->
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding MovieDate, StringFormat=d, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                                    Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.MovieTicketsDataGridDate}"/>

                <!--  Theatre -->
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Theatre},NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                                    Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.MovieTicketThreatre}" />

                <!--  Price -->
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Price},NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                                    Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.MovieTicketPrice}" />

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:CustomDataGrid>
```

Then this is what I have in my view model:

```
    private Visibility _movieTicketsGridVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    public Visibility MovieTicketsGridVisibility
    {
        get { return _movieTicketsGridVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _movieTicketsGridVisibility = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MovieTicketsGridVisibility));
        }
    }

    private readonly object _movieTicketLock = new object();
    private FastObservableCollection<MovieTicket> _ticketCollection = new FastObservableCollection<MovieTicket>();

    public MovieTicketsViewModel() : base()
    {
        // ...
        MovieTicketsGridVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MovieTicketsCollectionView.Source = _ticketCollection;
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_ticketCollection, _movieTicketLock);
        // ...
        LoadMovieDetails();
    }

    private void LoadMovieDetails()
    {
        // ...
        MovieTicketCount = myTicketRepository.LoadMovieTicketCount();
        IList<MovieTicket> tickets =
            myTicketRepository.LoadMovieTickets();
        _ticketCollection.ReplaceAll(tickets);
        // ...
    }
```

Here is the required converter:

```
public class DataGridHeaderCountConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string val = (value != null) ? value.ToString() : "0";
        string format = (parameter != null ? parameter.ToString() : "{0}");
        return (val != "0") ? format.Replace("{0}", val) : format.Replace("({0})", "");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```